# ActiveAdmin using POST instead of PATCH/DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin (master) on Rails 4.2 with rails-api. I've done all the proper configuration so that AA works properly. I can use index pages, show, use the edit form, etc. But when it comes time to take a destructive action, for some reason AA uses POST instead of the proper http verb. The result is a 404:

> No route matches [POST] "/admin/admin_users/1"

When I copy the request as a cURL via the chrome console, modify the HTTP method from POST to DELETE, everything works properly and the user is deleted. So why is ActiveAdmin using POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add the `Rack::MethodOverride` to my middleware stack (you can confirm it's missing by running `rake middleware`).

Add it like so:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, using activeadmin 1.0.0 and Rails 5.0.2.  The form has the correct html, but the controller was receiving a POST:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
```

I checked, the `Rack::MethodOverride` middleware was in place.

My issue was fixed by correcting the permit_params: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters.

I do not understand how that affects the POST/PATCH, but it did.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I also have strong parameters. Could you please help me how can i resolve this issue?